# Typescript declaration: why does this throw an error

Tags: angular, typescript, module, systemjs

I'm just learning Typescript. I'm writing an `Angular 2` app with `typescript 2`, using `SystemJS 0.15.31` as my module loader.

I'd like to define app-wide constants. in one file, and import it in my components as needed. This is what I have:

**root/systemjs.config.js**

```
System.config({
    map:{
        'app': 'dist',
        'config': 'dist/config',
        ...
    }
});
```

**root/dev/config.ts**

```
export module Config {
    var version:string = '1';
}
```

**root/dev/app/app.component.ts**

```
import {Config} from 'config';
...
export class AppComponent {
    ...
    version = Config.version;
}
```

After transpilation to Javascript, the `.ts` files are put in `dist/`. However, the typescript compiler shows this error on the first line of `app.component.ts` and in the browser, `AppComponent` doesn't see `Config.version`

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'config'.

What's the problem with my syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that SystemJS is expecting `dist/config` to be a folder.

Add an extension to the file path, like so:

```
map: {
    ...
    'config': 'dist/config.js' 
    ...
}
```

PS: 
`export module` is not typescript. I think you want:

```
export const Config = {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I made the change. The same error is thrown on the same `import {Config} from 'config'` line.  If I change to use a relative path `.. from '../config'`, things work without error.  Problem is the relative path changes from file to file so it doesn't scale well. It's in order to have one fixed path that I used the `SystemJS map` option in the OP.

Comment: how about this new answer?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that it made no difference over your initial answer. SystemJS has no trouble finding the config file even when the path is missing the file extension: I know this because the `version` variable value is correctly imported in the component. However I get the same error as before from the typescript compiler

Comment: in your question is says that, in the browser, the component can't see `config.version`

Comment: Yes That was true when I opened the thread because my initial code was `export module Config {...` (see the OP).  I then changed it to `export var Config = {...` and it started to work in the browser. I then modified your suggestion to use `export const Config = {...` (your code as it's currently written doesn't compile at all: `export const Config {...`). So things work in the browser, but the typescript compiler throws the same error from the OP